# Composite view callback order

Tags: javascript, marionette

I am facing an issue with Backnone Marionette, is for first time render of Composite View, callback order is

1. onRender
2. appendHtml - n times

But if I re-render same it will be

1. appendHtml - n times
2. onRender

and it return correct collection data for re-render method, first time collection will be blank as onRender executed before appendHtml completed.

Have anyone faced this issue? Is there any solution to this?

Thanks

Peter

Comment: I am having problem understanding your problem, do you mind showing the issue in a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an actual question to answer, so I'll just guess you want to do something once the collection has been rendered. For that purpose, you can respond to the view's "collection:rendered" event, or define an `onCollectionRendered` callback.